# Change Ubuntu 12.04 (with Gnome) number of workspaces via command line

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gnome, workspaces

I'm trying to change the **number of workspaces on my Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome** from a terminal. It's easily done by right clicking on the workspaces preview in the panel, but I would like to be able to do it from a shell script.

My guess is to go through some *gsettings org.gnome.* command, but so far I've been unable to find the proper schema and associated key to do that.

Would anyone have a tip ?

Thanks in advance for the answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of workspaces you can use:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces
```

To change the number of workspaces to 8 for example you can use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 8
```

Comment: Great, that does it all !

I had a look at org.gnome.desktop, but I didn't look all the way down to _vm_ :/

Thanks a lot Radu !